# ResizeEnd event is not triggered when resizing the form by maximize button?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, resize

In my application the `ResizeEnd` event is triggered when resizing the form by dragging the corners, but it will not be triggered when I click the maximize button.

The `Resize` event does not work in my scenario so I need to use `ResizeEnd` event.

Why is this event not triggered while resizing the form by maximize button? Or can anyone suggest alternatives?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [`ResizeEnd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.resizeend?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) event is raised when the user finishes resizing a form, typically by dragging one of the borders or the sizing grip located on the lower-right corner of the form, and then releasing it. It also is raised when the user moves a form.

If for any reason you need maximizing the window cause raising the `ResizeEnd` event you can raise the event this way:

```
const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
const int SC_MAXIMIZE = 0xF030;
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    base.WndProc(ref m);
    if (m.Msg == WM_SYSCOMMAND) 
    {
        if (m.WParam == (IntPtr)SC_MAXIMIZE) 
        {
            //the window has been maximized
            this.OnResizeEnd(EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

Note

- The [`Resize`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.resize?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) event is raised also when the form is maximized.
- The [`Layout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.layout?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) event is a suitable event if you want to handle a custom layout.

Comment: Hi Reza, Thanks for your answer. In my source, i have used Form as a property. So i can't accessed OnResizeEnd raise method by Form.

Comment: Hi, you're welcome :) If that form is one of your forms, you can simply add such code in a common base `Form` of all forms of your application. But if it's not your form and you don't have access to its non-public members to override `WndProc` and call `OnResizeEnd`, you can also apply a similar solution for another `Form` which you don't have access to it's non-public methods.

Comment: Thanks for this. Very helpful. I've also added so that the event triggers on the restore too `const int SC_RESTORE = 0xF120` if anyone is wondering.

Comment: Additionally, if the user maximizes/restores the window by double-clicking the header, slightly different messages will be sent: `0xF032` and `0xF122`.