# SizeChanged event but only after total change is done

Tags: c#, winforms, resize

I need to use the `SizeChanged` event of a windows `Chart` for replotting in correct scale whenever the user resises the form.

But while the user is resizing the form (normally, by dragging the form's borders), this event is fired a lot of times and I don't want to keep replotting during the total operation, **only when the user stops resizing** the form.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> While the user is resizing the form (normally, by dragging the form's borders), this event is fired a lot of times and I don't want to keep replotting

***You can handle*** this behavior by using the [Form.ResizeEnd Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.resizeend?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8). This event is raised when the user finishes resizing a form, typically by dragging one of the borders or the sizing grip located on the lower-right corner of the form, and then releasing it.

For example:

```
private void Form1_ResizeEnd(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   MessageBox.Show("You are in the Form.ResizeEnd event.");
}
```

**Update:**

As per comment below by @Reza Aghaei, this event will not be raised in case a user selects the `Maximize` button. Please [see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39654018/1797425) his answer there for more details.

References:

[Form.ResizeEnd Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.resizeend?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8) on Microsoft

Comment: Just be aware, [maximize button will not trigger resize end](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39654018/3110834).

Comment: @RezaAghaei updated to include your information in the post, thanks!